# Tomcat 7 starting - org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name?

Tags: tomcat

When I am starting the Tomcat 7 server I am getting the below error?Same works fine in Tomcat 6.

**Error in Eclipse Luna console:**

SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'onDemandAggregate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webaccess-servlet-crons.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'aggregateTransaction' while setting bean property 'aggregateHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aggregateTransaction' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webaccess-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webaccess-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webaccess-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1636)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aggregateTransaction' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webaccess-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webaccess-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webaccess-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 36 more

It will be helpful for me...
Thank you.

Comment: Check the lib folder in tomcat 6 for any extra jar file you seems to be missing a jar file, this might be the cause nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager. You should be able to resolve the issue after going throw this :

http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Comment: I have listed down the 2 different jar file in the Tomcat lib folder.Application works fine in the Tomcat 6.Problem happens only in Tomcat7.

Comment: @justMe Tomcat 6:
annotations.jar
catalina.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-ha.jar
ecj-4.3.1.jar
el-api.jar
jasper.jar
jasper-el.jar
jsp-api.jar
jta-1.1.jar
ojdbc14.jar
servlet-api.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
\n
Tomcat 7:
annotations.jar
catalina.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-ha.jar
ecj-4.3.1.jar
el-api.jar
jasper.jar
jasper-el.jar
jsp-api.jar
servlet-api.jar
tomcat-api.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
tomcat-jdbc.jar
tomcat-util.jar

Comment: what I meant was you might have an extra jar file in tomcat 6 lib that is not in tomcat 7 lib, sorry I don't think I was clear.

Comment: Yes you are correct added jta1.1jar and ojdbc14.jar inside the tomcat7 lib folder .problem solved.thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct added jta1.1jar and ojdbc14.jar inside the tomcat7 lib folder .
Problem solved.thank you for your time.